# How to reboot into the other operating system?

Tags: reboot

I've installed Windows 10 on HDD and after that Ubuntu on SSD. Now, when I try to reboot into windows, it wont't get me to the options menu, it will jump directly into Ubuntu OS. I'm looking to find a way to fix this. Thank you!

Comment: Start by doing, in Ubuntu, *sudo update-grub*. If it doesn't find a Windows entry then probably you installed the OSes in different modes (one in UEFI, one in Legacy (BIOS)). IF so you can only dual boot from the UEFI menu by changing the first boot device to the one where Windows is installed.

Comment: this is what I got ... `Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-38-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
`

Comment: So it's what I suspected and mentioned in the second sentence of the comment above. Your results show Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode but Windows i nowhere to be found which means it was installed in Legacy mode (Really??? Why?).

Comment: are you sure during installing ubuntu you didn't overwite Windows?

Comment: I'm so afraid of that..is there a way to check if I still have windows? But I'm sure that ubuntu was installed on ssd. I didn't intented to install in uefi or legacy, I think that's default for my asus rog gl552vw..

Comment: Disks or GParted (available in live media but not installed by default) can give you a graphical "map" to the partitions in either drive so it's quite easy to find out whether or not the Windows partitions are still there.

Comment: @CelticWarrior is there a terminal command?